# Dropzone maxFilesize has no effect in C# MVC project website

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone

A developer left us using dropzone.js [www.dropzonejs.com] which is all well and good but he set everything up to load max filesize of 1MB which is much too small for us.

Here's an example:

```
var dropzone = new Dropzone(document.body,
    { // Make the whole body a dropzone
        url: window.fileUploadUrl,
        acceptedFiles: "application/pdf, image/*, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, ",                
        previewTemplate: '<div></div>',                
        params: {
            id: model.TempId
        },
        maxFilesize: 1,
        clickable: "#upload"                
    });
```

So I thought it would simply be a case of altering the maxFilesize there to, say, 256 for 256MB instead of 1 for 1MB.

However, when I do this and try and upload a file that is say 100MB (anything above 1MB) I get this:

```
Invalid file - must be PDF, Image or Document and have a maximum size of 250Mb
```

I checked the defaults in dropzone.js and dropzone.min.js and they have as their default:

```
maxFilesize: 256,
```

I've read every article I can find, tried every configuration change I can think of, but nothing will allow me to upload anything greater than 1MB.

I can't help but think I'm missing something, does anyone have any ideas? Or any way to narrow down what might be the problem?

We're running the C# MVC website on IIS 7 on an AWS EC2 instance, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone with a similar problem who finds this - turns out it's nothing to do with dropzone, that was working correctly, but the problems is that out of the box, ASP.Net has a 4MB default upload limit.

I was obsessed with the idea it was a 1MB limit, but in actuality it was 4MB, I'd just been testing with sub 1MB files, and my next step up was much more than 4MB.

So, when I override this in the web.config entry, with an addition of a maxRequestLength value:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="262144" />
```

Things suddenly work fine.